# Django Query for two related models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-orm

I have an `Order` model that is related to `Booking` model as ForeignKey field. So, an `Order` can be related to multiple `Booking` objects.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    shop=models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    order_id=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    order_date=models.DateField(default=date.today)

class Booking(models.Model):
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    service=models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null = True)
```

My goal is to show `Order` with the related `Booking` objects like this:

```
<ul>
{% for order in orders %}
    <li>{{ order.order_id }}</li>
    <ul>
         {% for booking in BOOKINGS WITH THIS ORDER ID %}
         <li>{{ booking.service }}</li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In the template, with in each order, I want to be able to loop through bookings with that order id.

I am having trouble figuring out how to make the proper query to achieve that in the template.

I thought about creating a dictionary object to store and pass the related booking object details, but this does not seem to be the proper way to do this.

```
def shopDashboardPastBookings(request):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(shop_id = shopID ).exclude(order_date__gte = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)) )
    bookings = {}
    for order in orders:
        booking_query = Booking.filter(order = order )
        bookings[order.order_id] = booking_query 

    // should I be making separate queries for each orders like this?

    paginator = Paginator(orders, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_orders = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {
    'orders':paged_orders,
    'bookings':bookings,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard-pastbookings.html',context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, [prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) orders' bookings in the initial query in order to save db hits:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(...).exclude(...).prefetch_related('booking_set')
```

There shouldn't be a need to retrieve bookings to a separate context variable in the view. Then, in the template, just access a specific order's bookings via the FK's default [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
{% for booking in order.booking_set.all %}
```